# How to make pass the name of excel file as the argument to function

Tags: python, excel, function, arguments

```
def YrlyAverage(Excel):
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib as plt

    import numpy as np
    df = pd.read_excel (r'Excel')  # PANDAS WILL READ THE ENTIRE EXCEL SHEET AND STORE IT AS DATAFRAME
    print (df)
    arr = df.to_numpy()    #CONVERTING DATAFRAME TO ARRAY
    i = 0
    j = -1
    Avg1 =[] ; Avg2 =[] ; Avg3 =[] ; Avg4 =[];Avg5 =[] ; Avg6 =[]; Avg7 =[]; Avg9 =[];Avg10 =[]; Avg11=[]
    Avg12 =[] ; Avg13=[]
    for i in range(1912,2017,1):
        j=j+1
        n= (i - (i-(12*j)))+3
        node1 = arr[n:n+12,2]
        Avg1 =  np.append(Avg1,node1.mean(axis=0))
        node1 = []
        
        node2 = arr[n:n+12,3]
        Avg2 =  np.append(Avg2,node2.mean(axis=0))
        node2 = []
        
        node3 = arr[n:n+12,7]
        Avg3 = np.append(Avg3,node3.mean(axis=0))
        node3 = []
        
        node4 = arr[n:n+12,4]
        Avg4 = np.append(Avg4,node4.mean(axis=0))
        node4 = []
        
        node5 = arr[n:n+12,5]
        Avg5 = np.append(Avg5,node5.mean(axis=0))
        node5 = []
        
        node6 = arr[n:n+12,6]
        Avg6 = np.append(Avg6,node6.mean(axis=0))
        node6 = []
        
        node7 = arr[n:n+12,8]
        Avg7 = np.append(Avg7,node7.mean(axis=0))
        node7 = []
        
        node9 = arr[n:n+12,9]
        Avg9 = np.append(Avg9,node9.mean(axis=0))
        node9 = []
        
        node10 = arr[n:n+12,10]
        Avg10 = np.append(Avg10,node10.mean(axis=0))
        node10 = []
        
        node11 = arr[n:n+12,11]
        Avg11 = np.append(Avg11,node11.mean(axis=0))
        node11 = []
        
        node12 = arr[n:n+12,12]
        Avg12 = np.append(Avg12,node12.mean(axis=0))
        node12 = []
        
        node13 = arr[n:n+12,13]
        Avg13 = np.append(Avg13,node13.mean(axis=0))
        node13 = []

    return Avg1,Avg2,Avg3, Avg4, Avg5, Avg6, Avg7, Avg9, Avg10,Avg11 ,Avg12, Avg13;

Excel = 'D:\Cases-ANA\hsabharwal\project1\data\Scenarios\LTFD_12_00_1.xlsx'
YrlyAverage(Excel)
```

When I pass the excel file name. It gives the error as:
Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Excel'

Comment: [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Change `pd.read_excel (r'Excel')` to `pd.read_excel (Excel)`.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to make it working by above suggestion. But, now when I am trying to use Avg1, Avg2,....., Avg13. It is giving the error that Avg1 is not defined